# Mark a folder so it'll never hold more than a certain amount of data?

Tags: ftp

I'm setting up an FTP for a friend to send me large files. I have it all set up and open for him to read and write to one specific folder. Although my friend isn't really malicious I wouldn't want to let him fill that folder with more than a certain amount of data.

I've found that I could restrict the size of a single file upload, but nothing about that would prevent him from uploading hundreds of smaller files. Besides, I do want him to be able to send large files (that's the reason I'm setting this up).

What's the simplest way I can set it up so that the destination folder can't get larger than say 3GB? I might be able to do some sort of drive partitioning but I think that's a little overkill. I might move the ftp folder to a thumb drive, but that means I have to leave it plugged in all the time. And if I swap out drives, I might inadvertently give my friend access to a drive I don't want them to have access to.

I'm running IIS on Windows 10 Pro x64.

Comment: Do this on the server side through the ftp server software.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't believe File Server Resource Manager (which provides FTP quotas in IIS) is available on Windows 10 IIS. An alternative solution is described in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use a VHDX virtual disk for the FTP folder. Virtual disk images can be configured to have any desired size, allowing you to limit the amount of data that can be stored at the location the image is mounted. You can even use disk quotas to limit disk space usage at the account level.

- Create a VHDX disk image of the appropriate size in Disk Management (**Action** > **Create VHD**):

[image: Dialog box for creating disk image]

- Then double-click on the image file to mount it, format and partition it in Disk Management, and assign it a drive letter or mount it to a specific folder on the system folder. Right-click on the volume in Disk Management and select **Change Drive Letters and Paths...**, then assign it an appropriate location (the path where files will be uploaded via FTP).
- For even greater flexibility, you can set disk quotas so that individual user accounts can't exceed certain storage limits. These settings are available in the properties for the volume in **My Computer**. (If it isn't assigned a drive letter, you'll need to access the properties in Disk Management by right-clicking on the volume in order to set quotas.)
- You can unmount a disk image at any time by right-clicking on the disk to which the volume belongs (the part that says "Disk x, Basic") and selecting **Detach VHD**. If assigned a drive letter, you can right-click on the drive in **This PC** and select **Eject** to do the same.